# Salvar dados de um datagridview em um banco de dados

Tags: c#, datagridview

Estou querendo salvar mais de uma linha do meu datagridview no banco de dados, mas ele salva apenas a primeira linha e depois da erro dizendo que os parâmetros já foram definidos, queria saber onde eu estou errando

```
        MySqlConnection conn;
        conn = new MySqlConnection(conexao);
        conn.Open();

        cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO TesteCauaVendas VALUES(@Nome, @Cor, @Especie, @Quantidade, @Vendedor, @Data, @Cliente)", conn);

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dtCompra.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cor", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Especie", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantidade", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vendedor", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cliente", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);                        
           
               MessageBox.Show("Venda Realizada com Sucesso");
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);                   
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cada inserção deves ter uma execução da query,
ou seja cada vez vez que que queres fazer o insert crias o comando, atribuis os parâmetros e executas,

No teu código a solução seria passar a declaração da query (cmd) para dentro do for e também a execução para dentro do for (ExecuteNonQuery)

E já agora num cenário que inseres várias linhas e queiras ter a garantia que são todas gravadas ou em caso de falha não gravar, podes usar transações.

```
  try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtCompra.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO TesteCauaVendas VALUES(@Nome, @Cor, @Especie, @Quantidade, @Vendedor, @Data, @Cliente)", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cor", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Especie", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantidade", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vendedor", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cliente", dtCompra.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);                        
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       
        }

           MessageBox.Show("Venda Realizada com Sucesso");
```

Uma observação estás a informar o utilizador que o registo foi guardado antes de o guardar, para não induzir o utilizador em erro só devias notificar o utilizador quando o registo fosse efetivamente inserido.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou! Estava faltando um pouco de organização e lógica kkk.